# attach react app to an html div after creating bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've created a bundle of my react app using webpack as shown below:

**My webpack.config.js :**

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require("glob");
const { SourceMapDevToolPlugin } = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: glob.sync('./App.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'],
                plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
            }
            
        },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    {
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader']
                    })
                 
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                use: ['source-map-loader']  
                 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/, loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
      
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'style.css'})
    ]
};
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.11",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mycompany/picl": "^0.0.12-dev",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/App.js --output ./static/built/bundle.js --watch"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "8.0.0",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.6.0",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.44",
    "source-map-loader": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Running `yarn run dev` has generated a `bundle.js`, `style.css` and a `.svg` file inside `static\build` folder. However, I'm not sure how do I attach this `bundle.js` with a HTML div tag as I want to display this react app bundle in a simple HTML/Javascript app.

I looked at [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html). But they are adding a dom container inside their `like_button.js` but i don't have that option since my `js` file which is `bundle.js` is getting generated from my react app. Do I need to do something different to generate a `bundle.js` in such a manner that it can get attached to an HTML div?

I was planning to include the `bundle` and `css` like this in my `html` code as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Testing Jan 17</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="built/style.css"/>
    
</head>
<body>

<div id="reactAppDisplay"></div>
<script src="built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I'm not sure how at the time of generating `bundle.js` I should attache my app to the `id` `reactAppDisplay` so that my react app can be displayed on the web brwser?

Comment: you might be able to use an iframe. Have you considered that? Check out the last example in this post, looks mostly ok https://dev.to/pulljosh/how-to-load-html-css-and-js-code-into-an-iframe-2blc

Comment: @bcstryker I'm trying to avoid using iframe approach as that requires this react app to be deployed separately and also requires X-Frames related changes on the server. I've one app running this way so I'm aware of this approach. Btw, is there anything wrong with above approach in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need do is modify your `index.jsx` file to look like the following before building:

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <StrictMode>
        <App />
    </StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('reactAppDisplay')
);
```

this will compile your react app and append the result to the HTML element which id is `reactAppDisplay`

Comment: I see. So I have `index.js` which is like this `ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`. I will change the `root` to `reactAppDisplay` and generate the bundle again and see how it goes.

Comment: I don't have `index,jsx` so that's fine, right? It's `index.js`

Comment: If your `index.js` is likely to the one up then good. Change the targeted element id, build again and you should be good